# Dynamic font size with setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uifont

I have got a `label` contained in a `UIView`. The bounds are set the same as the `UIView` and so the `label` should always be as big as the `view` is.

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
[self.label setText:@"3"];
[self.label setTextColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f]];
[self.label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold" size:400]];
[self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[self.label setNumberOfLines:1];
[self.label setMinimumScaleFactor:0.1];
[self.label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

[self addSubview:self.label];
```

As you can see, I am setting the `font size` to 400, which is way to big and want to cut it down with the `setMinimumScaleFactor`. But it's not working for me. 
Any suggestions…?

Comment: I have tried this it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880690/how-to-adjust-the-uilabel-width-according-to-the-string

Comment: But this is just updating the rect and not the font size or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe it didn't work because your string is only "3" If you set it to something longer it would trigger the resizing. The flag you set only adjusts font size if the width of the string doesn't fit. It doesn't care about the height of the string.